# Route with different path based on parent route param

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With the new React Router V6, the handling of routes changed a lot. I'm currently struggling to build the following structure

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path=":locale" element={<OtherRoutes/>} />
        <Route path="*" element={<p>404</p>} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The `OtherRoutes` component should return different paths based on the parent param, but this code does not work. I also tried with absolute paths, but this does not work as well.

```
const OtherRoutes = () => {
    const {locale} = useParams();

    if (locale === "de") {
        return <Route path="seite" element={<GermanPage/>}/>
    }

    return <Route path="page" element={<EnglishPage/>}/>
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: OtherRoutes component already returns a Route, why do you pass it inside another Route in BrowserRouter?

Comment: what is `Routes`? did you mean `Switch`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz `Routes` is the replacement for `Switch` in React Router 6. As I understand from the documentation, it's pretty much the same https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Comment: oh cool, hadn't learned about v6 yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was pretty simple. I just needed to make the first route `:locale` to match all routes like `:locale/*`